# Domain registered through third party which is now defunct

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, whois

A client's website is registered on a domain which has a protected whois. The website and domains were setup via a third party company which went under years ago but we are unsure if the company was bought over or what. Despite the fact this happened years ago, the domain is still registered and still points to my clients website. It looks like the domain and whois protection gets renewed every year. Initial registration was nearly 10 years ago.

I don't care for the website, but how do I go about claiming the clients domain on their behalf? Transfer is of course prohibited. Is it worth contacting the registrar to try and get the details of who has the domain details or would I have more luck using google to track down what company bought the original company and contact them directly?

Comment: what is the TLD?

Comment: the TLD is `.com`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to do, it isn't clear.  You seem to know who the registrar is, you should be able to log in and check the registrant contact information and edit it if needed.

Comment: Log into what? I have no details about this clients site apart from the the URL of the domain they gave me. I used a WHOIS site to look up the contact information but it is all protected. I just have the raw WHOIS record and the only relevant information is the registrar name. I would have assumed since WHOIS protection was purchased I probably wont have much luck contacting the registrar.. but I have no idea since there seems to be little information on the internet about the process of reclaiming a domain

Comment: whois should tell you who is the registrar (not the reseller), that is who you need to contact.

Comment: @myol You have two options here: 1) Send emails to the email address listed in the registrant info - even though that's concealed through a proxy, it will still be forwarded to the registrant's email address. If your client has control over their domain's email, have them setup a catch-all email address beforehand. If they receive the reply, then they can likely gain access to domain control panel with the registrar by having the password resent to them. If the email however goes to the third-party, you might still get a reply back if they're willing to help.

Comment: 2) Have your client contact the registrar themselves to work with them on verifying the ownership of the domain. You won't be able to help them with that however. See:  [Recovering domain name from a person I can't find](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37914/recovering-domain-name-from-a-person-i-cant-find?rq=1)

Comment: ahh...yes...you can't contact the registrar @myol, needs to be your client.